Is there any way to create a new window terminal (pseudo-terminal) using a command without setting env $DISPLAY?
I am currently building an open-source utility (plugin), which requires a new terminal window (pseudo-terminal) to become more effective whenever it gets executed.
I was using gnome-terminal to execute task scripts. It was working well on linux machine where everything was setup, like X11 forwarding, $DISPLAY environment variable.
When I tried it on my mac, machine, my utility became useless.
Firstly, gnome-terminal was not present, so for time being I used xterm instead. Now the issue arised, xterm needs **$DISPLAY** to be set.
I set it to following combinations:
``
DISPLAY=<host>:0
DISPLAY=<host>.<domain>:0
DISPLAY=<host>:0.0
DISPLAY=<host>.<domain>:0.0
DISPLAY=localhost:0
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
DISPLAY=:0.0
DISPLAY=:0
``

None worked. It seems it was due to X11 forwarding issue, which I am not able to setup. I thought to set it up, but many users might also require it to setup too, if using my utility.
With all your help, is there any better solution to this problem?
I just needs a new local terminal window (pseudo-terminal), wherever my script is being run.
The main challenge is that, it requires a standard solution, so that it can work on all user space, whoever can simply use vim (thats my main goal).
As major vim usage is on terminal, so I need a new terminal window (pseudo-terminal) for that!
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

You can use the shell directly (for example by running bash -c yourcommand)

Thanks @GhorbanM.Tavakoly. I already tried it, it executes the command but it won't give you a new window.

Okay @Barmar. But my question was indeed related to programming, i need a programming statement which gets executed at user side, and prompt them a new window, without any pre-setups. Yes, it's not totally, but it's still is.

You need XQuartz (or any other X Windows Server) installed.
